# Using Java stream() API to filter out single element without List

Tags: java, filter, stream, collectors, collect

I wonder if there is a way to filter out a single element directly in Java by using stream().filter() but without the need of creating a list and getting the 0 index.

My code looks something like this:

```
String foo = stringList
            .stream().filter(item -> item.equals("foo"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0);
```

I would like to get the element without the need of creating a list.

Thanks

Comment: String foo = Arrays.asList("foo", "Bar", "Baz")
                .stream().filter(x -> x.equals("foo")).findFirst().get();

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd call `findFirst()`:

```
String foo = stringList
            .stream().filter(item -> item.equals("foo"))
            .findFirst().get();
```

As a bonus, it returns an `Optional` which allows you to handle the case where no element matches the filter:

```
String foo = stringList
            .stream().filter(item -> item.equals("foo"))
            .findFirst().orElse(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is `findFirst` or `findAny`, this will return an Optional:

```java
String foo = stringList.stream()
                       .filter("foo"::equals)
                       .findAny()
                       .orElse(null);
```

This will also take care of the edge case where the created list is empty and throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.